# How to create intranet sites for different departments within an organization in office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, intranet

Best practices for creating intranet sites for different departments of an organization.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple options to structure your department site hierarchy.

- Each department gets its own site collection.

[image]

- Single site collection. all department sites are subsites, just 1 level below the homepage.

[image]

- Single site collection. all departments are organized into a hierarchy of subsites according to function.

[image]

Each option has its advantage and disadvantage please check this at [How to structure sites in your SharePoint Intranet](http://sharepointmaven.com/structure-sites-sharepoint-intranet/)

## **Credit to** [How to structure sites in your SharePoint Intranet](http://sharepointmaven.com/structure-sites-sharepoint-intranet/)

See also [SharePoint Department Site Example](http://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-department-site-template/)

**Note:** it's recommended to use **Team Site template** to can **save the site as template** and be able to reuse it with other departments. for more details check [MISSING SAVE SITE AS TEMPLATE IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **video tutorial** which will help you understand **how to create  different departments** subsites under one root site with each subsite having different look & feel.  This video will also help you to brush up your knowledge as how to navigate between different subsites, embed you tube link in SharePoint, group the list by a particular column and how to apply themes for different subsites

Video: **[How to create sites in your SharePoint Intranet for different departments](https://www.paragyte.com/blog/sharepoint-training-create-sharepoint-intranet-sites-for-hr-sales-and-it-department)**